# Execute Find and Replace function in an open Word document from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

From within Excel, I need to open a Word document (I succeeded at this) and then perform (programatically) a Find/Replace inside that document (No success at this).

The reason to use an Excel macro is that the replacement text is taken from some Excel cells.

```
Sub Word_find_replace_attempt_from_Excel()

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test.doc") 'it exists already
    With WordDoc
        Find.Execute _
            FindText:="a", _
            ReplaceWith:="b", _
            Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer shows how to do it:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817645/6481438](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817645/6481438)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set a referenece to MS Word, but make sure that declare consts for any MS Word Enumerations that you use.

```
Sub Word_find_replace_attempt_from_Excel()
    Const wdReplaceAll = 2

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test.doc")
    With WordDoc.Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:="a", ReplaceWith:="b", _
                 Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Zillion dear Thomas! You'll never know how I spent two days Googling before steping forward to ask. Your answer's right on spot! :)